# Text to the center despite of different padding from sides

Tags: html, css

I need to add header text to the center but it can not exceed some limits to the right and left, those are different in size. When I am adding padding or margin center moves along with it.

How can I add different padding form side but still have text on center? 
[image]

```
<div>
  <h1 style="position: absolute; padding: 26px 30px 0 90px;"> Some text here</h>
</div>
```

Comment: And where's your code?

Comment: whats the use of this? To help you, i need more than just a context.

are you hoping to have something like a sidebar, and would like the text aligned with the new 'main area'

Comment: Basically it is header for mobile web app, that should have header like iOS apps do. But with long headers it is overlapping back button name, so I need to limit header from left and from right.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a block element like h1 tag or p tag. give your limit as 'max-width' and give css property `margin:0 auto`.  it will be in center and it will not exceed the limit

Comment: max-width can be different as total screen width can be diffrent

Comment: then give it percentage

Comment: this way you can align to the center but the limits on left and right is the same. I need to be it different in size. lets say: left 90px and right 30px. The problem here is that if I do so text center moves about 60px to the right side, and I need to stay it in the same plase as limits would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your div too.

Then just use padding on the h1 element to align as needed?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b0kr1bs/1/)

```
<div style="border:1px solid silver; height:100px; padding-left:300px; padding-right:90px;">
<h3 style="margin-left:100px;">Some text here</h3>
```

If this is not what you need please post your code.

Comment: task: set different limits for text in left and right side. lets say left 90px and right 30px and text to stay in the very center of main container. If I add margin or padding this way, the center of text moves as well, in this case about 30px

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Modify my fiddle, save and give me the link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2b0kr1bs/2/
text is not in the very center of container, it has moved to right

Comment: I will need you to post your actual code on why you need to apply that padding to the h3. I fixed it by adding margin-right to the h3 but I think you are doing this unnecessarily. http://jsfiddle.net/2b0kr1bs/3/